# Turn Tags into Links in Search Results

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, search

When a user searches for a certain tagged iamge I want them to be able to click on the tag and re-direct them on a page which contains all the images with that tag.
E.g. if I click Italy, all the pictures which have ***Italy*** as tags will be displayed.
Can I use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module for it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways,

1. Using the module [Similar By Terms](https://www.drupal.org/project/similarterms)
2. Using views, [Read more here](http://www.pixelwrapped.com/blog/related-articles-block-view-nodes-common-taxonomy-terms)

Comment: I have done it using Views - Is there any way to tag each of the images singularly and not the whole page (node)